# Why powerbi.load method is not working anymore?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-js-api

I'm embedding powerbi reports on my page via powerbi js embedded (ajax) and I'm having problems with getting pages from powerbi reports.

I've already tried the .load method and report.getPages() throws this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"data":"","status":401,"activityId":"xxx","requestId":"yyy","responseRequestId":null,"pendingRequestCount":0}
```

[Screenshot of console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpSzT.png)

My JS is like this:

```
tab == null ? 0 : tab;
// call load() instead of embed() to load the report while delaying the rendering process
var report = powerbi.load(embedContainer, config);
// when loaded event occurs, set current page then call render()
report.on("loaded", function () {
    console.log("loaded event executing");
    // call to get Pages collection
    report.getPages().then(
        function (pages) {
        // inspect pages in browser console
        console.log(pages);
        // display specific page in report
        var startPage = pages[1]; // this selects the second page
        config.pageName = startPage.name;
        // Call report.render() to display report
        report.render(config);
    });
});
```

I expect the load of the report before the renderization of the page, and not after.

Answer (score 0):

this is a workaround,

```
var embedContainer = $(embedid)[0];
var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
if(tab != null) {
    report.on('loaded', function () {
        report.getPages().then(function (pages) {
            pages[tab].setActive();
        });
    });
}
```

But the first page of the report shows eitherway.